# tail to awk pipe do not append if exists in file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, tail

**Edit: Instead of tossing out the duplicate data I want it to "overwrite" the duplicate data, meaning leave the data but update the timestamp**

Problem 1:

I have a command line as follows,

```
tail -f /some/file.log | awk '$2>10 (if (!($1 in a)) print $1, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); a[$1]=1 ;system("")}' > /some/filteredfile.log
```

However, I would like the output from this to only add the text to file if it isn't already there (in the 1st column), **and if it is there, update the timestamp (in the second column)**

Comment: Only one question at a time, please.

Comment: You only want to add the contents of `$1` to the file if no other line in the output file already contains that content?

Comment: Etan-Correct, no duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tail -f /some/file.log | awk ' $2>10 {if (!($1 in a)) print $1; a[$1]=1; system("")}' > /some/filteredfile.log
```

Comment: Shows a syntax error in my awk (3.1.7). At the ! and at the print

Comment: Works! Any idea on Part 2 or should I mark this as the answer and open a 2nd question?

Comment: I'm assuming this only works if the file is empty in the first place correct? That may be ok for my use case but just checking

Comment: @"I'm assuming this only works if the file is empty in the first place correct": You are anyway truncating it by `>`, not appending to it.

Comment: For second part, you can have a look at [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)...

Comment: If the data already exists in the 1st column (not the date column) how would I overwrite that and update the timestamp?

Comment: as opposed to tossing the data out

Answer (score 0):

One problem two part may be:

```
tail -f file.txt | awk -v date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%h%m%s")" '$2>10 {print date, $1; system("")} ' > output.log
```

It should solve your 2nd part, working for me.

Comment: %Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S on my system

Comment: How do I remove them after X days now?

Comment: Problem, it puts the same date/time in the file no matter when the data was actually added